# How to convert time written "h.mm" to decimal form with Python?

Tags: python

I prompt the user to input what time they start and finish their job. Then I need to calculate what they will earn (given a 97 currency/hour salary). The answer should also not have any decimals (so it should be rounded off). I can't seem to get it to work though.

As shown below, I tried taking the difference between the two inputs from the user and then splitting them to hours and minutes. After that just doing the calculations.

```
difference = round(float(finishing_time)-float(start_time), 2)
hours, minutes = str(difference).split(".")
salary_hours = int(hours)*97
salary_minutes = int(minutes)//60*97
salary = salary_hours + salary_minutes
```

So if start_time = 8.30 and finishing_time = 11.15 the salary should be 267, but I get 291 currency.

Comment: I don't think you want to be using floor division for the `salary_minutes`, there. That's not your main problem, though. If I subtract `9.00-8.59`, that will return `0.41`, although it should be only a one-minute difference. I recommend evaluating both the start and finish individually, then subtracting their monetary values.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try that. :)

Comment: Split before the difference, otherwise you will have 11.15-8.30 = 2.85
2*97 + 85//60*97 = 3*97 = 291

Comment: Only problem is I get, for example, 11-8 = 3, which isn't correct as it needs to be 2?

Comment: when working with times your best to use some sort of date time module. What if my start time is 23:30 and finish time is 00:30. I would have worked one hour but would be paid for 23 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to be careful of, is the rounding off that occurs at every level, which also occurs when you do math by hand and pencil! There is a reason why when you perform calculations one typically does the rounding off when the entire calculation has been performed otherwise one would come up with a vastly different answer as you pointed out.

I'd tackle this perhaps by doing something like this

```py
from datetime import datetime
# quick way to generate a datetime object with start time would be like
start_time = datetime.now()
# replace the hours and minutes you want in your case its
start_time = start_time.replace(hour=8, minute=30)
end_time = start_time.replace(hour=11, minute=15)
# calling replace returns a new distinct datetime object


def calculate_salary(start_time, finish_time, pay_rate):
    # will be in seconds
    delta_seconds = finish_time - start_time
    # convert to hours
    hours_worked = (delta_seconds.seconds) / 3600
    # calculate pay
    pay = hours_worked * pay_rate
    return pay
```

In this case calling the function gives a value of

```py
In [1]: calculate_salary(start_time, end_time, 97)
Out[1]: 266.75
```

Comment: I like it! However, is it possible to get the user to input the times instead of changing the code? Also, I'm guessing I can use round() at the end, before I return the pay? (No decimals allowed in the answer so it needs to be rounded off :))

Comment: If you can imagine it and ask the question, it is possible. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

While i dont advocate doing calculations on time without a time module. I assume you know what your doing and that your calculations are simple I.E they wont rolle over midnight and the finish time will always be greater than the start time and finish on the same day. With that in mind the following code should produce your result without using a datetime module. However like @william bright answer, a datetime module would be my prefernce for code like this.

```
def get_hours(time_string):
    time_split = time_string.split(".")
    whole_hours = int(time_split[0])
    fraction_hours = int(time_split[1]) / 60
    return whole_hours + fraction_hours

start_time=input("start time: ")
finish_time=input("finish_time: ")
total_hours = get_hours(finish_time)-get_hours(start_time)
salary = total_hours*97
print(round(salary))
```

OUTPUT

```
start time: 8.30
finish_time: 11.15
267
```

Comment: You are correct about the part about not rolling over midnight, but a full solution is always nice :) (But not part of my homework assignment). Is it possible to get the user to input the values instead?

Comment: updated to take input. However it would be good practice to validate your input before processing it.

Comment: I would totally be on it, but this code is intended as a starting point so that we can build onto it later. I do have a solution though, not sure if I'm allowed to post the whole thing though? :/

Comment: If either Williams or my answer solved your question please dont forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Well see, they were good answers, but not what I was after, if that makes sense? I have come up with a solution that isn't fool proof, given that I'm going to continuing buildning on it in my course.

Comment: It doesnt really make any sense to honest. you gave a problem which your code couldnt solve and both answers provided you with a solution to your problem. So i dont really get what you mean by its not what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

So, my bad for perhaps being unclear in my statement, but since this is a work in progress for the next couple weeks/months, what I came up with was the following:

```
starting_time = input("At what time did you start working? ")
finishing_time = input("At what time did you finish working? ")
hours1, minutes1 = starting_time.split(".")
hours2, minutes2 = finishing_time.split(".")
minutes1 = float(minutes1)/60
starting_time_new = float(hours1)+minutes1
minutes2 = float(minutes2)/60
finishing_time_new = float(hours2)+minutes2
salary = round((finishing_time_new-starting_time_new)*97)
print("Started working at:",b)
print("Stopped working at:",s)
print("Your salary is",salary,"currency.")
```

The solution from where I started was to just focus on changing the minutes to the correct decimals instead of focusing on the hours too.

I am well aware that it is far from perfect, in fact, it is probably really bad. However, I am new to programming in Python and taking a course to be better.